# How to print a '\n' character in Hex in c++

Tags: c++, cout, carriage-return

I am trying to print the hexidecimal value of '\n' using cout.

```
cout<< hex << '\n' << dec<< endl;
```

whenever that line of code is reached it just moves to a new line it does not print the hex value.
Thank you guys very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Streaming an actual `'\n'` character as-is will always output a line break.  You need to type-cast the value to an integer instead:

```
cout <<  hex << (int)'\n' << dec << endl;
```

Comment: I think `static_cast` is more appropriate as a C style cast here?